# weird behavior with pthreads and some primitive thread-pooling

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

so I though I finally figured out how to do these pthreads. Basically my code prints out some information in for loop 5 times, it changes the pointers witin the struct that is passed so different information can be changed while the thread is running. Anyway sometimes it works... and sometimes it prints out a part or sometimes it prints out gibberish!od

I hope somebody can point out my error.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_THREADS     5
#define NUM_LOOP        50


typedef struct infos {

   size_t               mainloop;

} infos;

typedef struct thread_specs {

   infos               *infos;

   size_t               thread_id;

   pthread_mutex_t      busy_mutex;
   pthread_cond_t       work_signal;

   pthread_barrier_t   *startup_barrier;

} thread_specs;


void *printtest(void *arg) {
   size_t i,sleep; 

   // casting passed information to struct
   thread_specs *thread_stuff= (thread_specs*)(arg);

   // accquiring mutex lock and wait for all threads to do the same
   pthread_mutex_lock(&(thread_stuff->busy_mutex));
   pthread_barrier_wait(thread_stuff->startup_barrier);

   while (1) {
         // wait for signal form main
         pthread_cond_wait(&(thread_stuff->work_signal), &(thread_stuff->busy_mutex));

         for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
            // do some stuff the random sleep is just the make it a little more non-deterministic
            sleep=rand()%100000;
            printf("main: %3i | thread: %3i | loop: %2i\n",thread_stuff->infos->mainloop,thread_stuff->thread_id,i); // thread_stuff->infos.real
            usleep(sleep);
         }

   }

}


int main () {

   // init pthread data types and the structs used.
   pthread_t         threads[NUM_THREADS];

   infos             infostruct[NUM_LOOP];
   thread_specs      thread_info[NUM_THREADS];
   pthread_barrier_t init_barrier;

   size_t            i,j;

   srand(time(0));

   printf("\n\n");

   // initialize barrier used to sync threads and main
   pthread_barrier_init(&init_barrier,NULL,NUM_THREADS+1);

   // pthread creation loop, passes the barrier as a pointer to the thread_specs struct also initializes the mutex and condition
   for (i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++) {
      thread_info[i].thread_id=i;
      thread_info[i].startup_barrier=&init_barrier;
      pthread_mutex_init(&(thread_info[i].busy_mutex), NULL);
      pthread_cond_init(&(thread_info[i].work_signal), NULL);

      if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, printtest, &thread_info[i] )) {
         printf("ERROR creating thread");
      } else {
         printf("SUCCES creating thread #%i\n",i);
      }

   }

   // wait for all threads to have acquired ownership of the mutex

   pthread_barrier_wait(&init_barrier);

   printf("created all threads\n");


   // loop to iterate of the loop to check if threads are busy and assign work to them if they arent. 
   // the thread MUST be busy if it currently holds the busy_mutex mutex, if it doesn`t it is waiting on the condition

   i=0;while(i<NUM_LOOP) {

      for (j=0;j<NUM_THREADS;j++) {

         if ((pthread_mutex_trylock(&(thread_info[j].busy_mutex)))==0) {
            infostruct[i].mainloop=i;
            thread_info[j].infos=&infostruct[i];
            pthread_cond_signal(&(thread_info[j].work_signal));
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(thread_info[j].busy_mutex));
            ++i;
         }

      }

   }

   // crude wait to wait for all threads to finish their last work
   for (j=0;j<NUM_THREADS;j++) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&(thread_info[j].busy_mutex));
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&(thread_info[j].busy_mutex));
   }

   printf("\n!!DONE!!\n");

   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can post some expected output and some of the gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

> sometimes it prints out a part or sometimes it prints out gibberish!

To `printf()` `size_t` use the `"zu"`.

Answer (score 0):

For the times where only part is printed out might be because there's a race when the main thread performs a `trylock()` and the corresponding thread might not have reached the point where the `pthread_cond_wait()` releases the mutex.

In that situation, the thread's condition variable will never get signaled.

Comment: no, the loop repeats. the problem whats that a signal doesn`t wake up a thread immediately. it is legal for the loop to signal the thread multiple times before it wakes up.

Comment: I guess I'm not entirely clear what problems you are seeing.  I understand that there's a outer loop that provides the main thread the capability to signal a previously locked thread, however that would mean the when the previously locked thread does get signaled, `i` will have been incremented so some instances of `i` will not get printed by some threads. Possibly. Or at least, that's what it would seem to me (I haven't actually compiled and run your program). I'm still not sure exactly what the gibberish out is.

Comment: the gibberish was likely because I didn`t use the correct printf argument. I have not seen it since. And you are correct that is skips some 'i' and that was the problem. I cant really post the entire output of the code as it is probably to long. However I have posted on the c programming board including output, I now know my problem. But I think I will redo it with a linked list type format. http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/162431-pthread-weird-behavior-signal-condition.html